# jquery push the key and value into array

Tags: jquery

I have the initial array in the following way:

```
var bankNamesList = [{
    'BARODA': 'BARODA'
}, {
    'AB': 'AB'
}];
```

Then i am looping the values and appended to main variable and constructing a drop-down

```
var bankNames = '<ul class="root" id="exp-bank-names">';
$.each(bankNamesList, function() {
    $.each(this, function(name, value) {
        bankNames += '<li><a href="#" name="' + name + '">' + value + '</a></li>';
    });
});
bankNames += '</ul>';
$('.submenu-bank-list').html(bankNames);
```

How do i push the new value in to an array.

i tried in the following way, but no luck.

```
var nameAttr = 'SBI';    
bankNamesList.push({nameAttr:nameAttr});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create an object and its properties using an object literal, the name to the left of the `:` is taken literally (pun intended). It doesn't look up a variable name, it uses the text you actually write.

So your example at the end:

```
var nameAttr = 'SBI';    
bankNamesList.push({nameAttr:nameAttr});
```

is actually the same as if you'd written this:

```
bankNamesList.push({ 'nameAttr': 'SBI' });
```

It looks like you probably meant it to do this, similar to the other elements of the `bankNamesList` array:

```
bankNamesList.push({ 'SBI': 'SBI' });
```

You could do that this way:

```
var nameAttr = 'SBI';
var item = {};
item[nameAttr] = nameAttr;
bankNamesList.push(item);
```

Comment: Nice answer.+1 (useful for me)

Answer (score 4):

You just need quotes around key:

```
var nameAttr = 'SBI';
bankNamesList.push({
    'nameAttr': nameAttr
});
```

Comment: That does the same thing as the original code at the end of the question. `{foo:bar}` and `{'foo':bar}` are no different from each other: they both create an object with a single property named `foo` whose value comes from the variable `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
 var anser_array = [];
 var KeyValuePair = '{"Qid"' + ":" + Question_id + "," + "Ans" + ":" + answer_id + "}";
 anser_array.push(KeyValuePair);
```